# TF400916: The current configuration is not valid for this feature.

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We are running TFS 2017 and when external users try to access the dashboard shows the error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

When accessing the "work" menu the following error: "TF400916: The current configuration is not valid for this feature. This feature cannot be used until a Team Foundation Administrator corrects the configuration" -> details: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

At the moment that kind of problems are only reported by users accessing the TFS from outside of the company's network.

Anyone have any ideas what could be causing this error? TIA

Comment: Do all users in your company's network not see this error? Do they access the same team project? Usually, error TF400916 is due to the Process Administrator misconfigured backlog levels. Please let the external users access other team projects to see whether they would get this error too.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar issues when my work items levels were configured incorrectly. Here, this might not be the case, since you are able to see it correctly for you. However to get a better idea what is wrong, you could go to the application tier machine hosting your TFS, go to the "Event Viewer", and look for the errors in the "Debug" log, under the "Microsoft-Team Foundation Server" node, as shown below:

[image: Debug log location]

If the error is listed there, you could view the "Details" of it, and hopefully you would see where this is coming from.